# SAS: Variable list contains names with '-' symbol, resulting in error during keep= statement

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have SAS datasets with multiple variables like H9999-999-999-999. However, I need to drop the unnecessary columns and am using a variable list(ParamList) to do that:

```
proc sql;
select _NAME_ into :ParamList separated by ' ' 
from uniquePlanList;
quit;
%put ParamList = &ParamList.;

proc sql;
create table test as
select * from out.seq_summ(keep=BPT_Cat &ParamList.);
run;
```

Because my variables contain '-' symbols I receive the following errors:

ERROR 214-322: Variable name - is not valid.

ERROR 214-322: Variable name 000 is not valid.

ERROR 80-322: Expecting a variable name.

ERROR: Invalid value for the KEEP option.

ERROR: Invalid option name -000.

ERROR: Some options for file OUT.SEQ_SUMM were not processed because of errors or warnings noted above.

I know if I were to list out the variables like this:

(keep=BPT_Cat 'H9999-999-999-999'n 'H9999-999-999-998'n)

Then the code would work. But I have some datasets with hundreds of variables. Is there a better way to drop the unnecessary columns than using a variable list? Or is there some clever way to read in the variable list as a string?
I tried using this:

(keep=BPT_Cat %str(&ParamList.)) but that gave me the same errors as above.

Comment: Consider setting `options validvarname=V7` so that you don't have to deal with - in the name at all. It's useful for labels, but it makes it a hassle to deal with overall and definitely when coding.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `NLITERAL()` function to generate names in a form that you can use in code.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(_NAME_)
  into :ParamList separated by ' ' 
  from uniquePlanList
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
proc sql;
select quote(_NAME_)||"n" into :ParamList separated by ' ' 
from uniquePlanList;
quit;
%put ParamList = &ParamList.;

proc sql;
create table test as
select * from out.seq_summ(keep=BPT_Cat &ParamList.);
run;
```

Don't have SAS with me at the moment can't really test it.